# Bukkit.getIp() in player.sendMessage - Possible solution?

Tags: bukkit

I'm making a plugin for my staff that can help them with some basic information.
I'm trying to add a /ip for the server that will show the server ip, instead of the dns that they connect to.

I'm trying something like this

```
var InfoIP = Bukkit.getIp();
player.sendMessage("Server Ip: " + InfoIP);
```

Apparently it does work with Bukkit.getPort(); but it doesnt work with the ip.
Is there another way to fix this?

I'm not looking for anything like this

```
var myip = "0.0.0.0";
player.sendMessage("Server Ip:" + myip);
```

I want the myip to be filled by the getIp instead of manually filling it.

Hopefully someone has a solution for this :)
tnx.

Comment: So you want it to show `***.***.***.***:port`? *EX: 182.118.145.123:25562*

Comment: You could use InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName(), but the name it returns may not be what you are looking for. Here's more:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348711/recommended-way-to-get-hostname-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to use the getIP method you must define it in your server properties.

there should be a line called server ip.
once you have defined your ip in the properties it will return the ip.
 when you use the getIP method.

Comment: it's working with a proxy so the server.properties aren't loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use:

```
player.sendMessage(getServer().getAddress() + ":" + getServer().getPort());
```

hope this helped

~~
AceStudios

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
if (!getServer().getPort() == "25565") {
player.sendMessage(getServer().getAddress() + ":" + getServer().getPort());
}
else {
player.sendMessage(getServer.getAddress());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Bukkit.getIP();` try using `Bukkit.getServer().getAddress();`