# Environment variable not accessible if Apache Camel run in Crontab of Centos

Tags: java, cron, apache-camel

I have one jar file which contain camel route to run it from cron job i
created shell script

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception
{
 String host=exchange.getContext().resolvePropertyPlaceholders("{{env:HOSTNAME}}");
}
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar my.jar
```

Now when i run

`sh test.sh` it is able to access environment variable, but when i run from
cron job it throw null pointer exception for  `{{env:HOSTNAME}}`

Following is my cron

```
cat > /etc/cron.d/reboot << EOF
* * * * * root /usr/bin/flock -w 1 -E 0 /tmp -c /test.sh 2>&1 |
/usr/bin/tee /dev/tty1
EOF
```

Comment: Worth looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348711/recommended-way-to-get-hostname-in-java

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27291/8174