# Bad behavior with InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() in Java 8

Tags: java, networking, network-programming, hosts, inetaddress

I need to know the name of the current computer.

The simplest method is by running:

```
java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
```

With OpenJDK 7 in a Linux machine, the result is correct, as reported by the system command `hostname`.

But with OpenJDK 8, the returned name is `localhost`, which is useless.

Why the different behavior?
How can I get the real name with Java 8?

Related questions:

- [Why does InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() return a value different from bash "hostname"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143880/why-does-inetaddress-getlocalhost-gethostname-return-a-value-different-from)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`getCanonicalHostName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getCanonicalHostName--) rather than [`getHostName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getHostName--)!

Comment: In my case, `getCanonicalHostName()` provides same result than `getHostName()`

Answer (score -1):

My `/etc/hosts` file is like this:

```
127.0.0.1           localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 myserver
```

then:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName().equals("localhost")
```

If I change it to this:

```
127.0.0.1           myserver localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
```

then:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName().equals("myserver")
```

Java 8 is more sensitive to ordering than Java 7, which returns always right result.

*UPDATE*:  Further investigation has shown that with CentOS 6, this is the behavior: Java 8 is ordering-dependent.  In CentOS 7, Java 8 works like Java 7.

Comment: Has your query been resolved? It seems you're simply adding contents of hosts file. Shouldn't this be a part of the question?

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful, it has been solved.  This is a workaround to a bug in Java 8.

Comment: @david.perez Is there actually a bug in Java 8, or did you just decide that this is a bug?

Comment: I'm not worried if it's a bug, but it is at least a change to behaviour.