# InetAddress.getHostName() does not return expected reverse name lookup from remote IP, like linux Host command

Tags: java, networking, dns, inetaddress

I have a simple java program that will print the dns name of IP address.

```
package p1;

import java.net.InetAddress;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName("201.23.160.63").getHostName());
        System.out.println(InetAddress.getByName("191.207.99.75").getHostName());

    }
}
```

the above program displays

- 201-23-160-63.gprs.claro.net.br
- 191.207.99.75

However, on the command line (linux host command), the dns for the two IPs are found.
[Command line IPs dns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CruqO.png)

Why does InetAddress.getHostName() not get the dns for IP 191.207.99.75 (191-207-99-75.user.vivozap.com.br) as shown in the command line? or what would be a way to achieve this in java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName() return a value different from bash "hostname"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143880/why-does-inetaddress-getlocalhost-gethostname-return-a-value-different-from)

Comment: These are different commands. One uses the Host command to get the dns from a remote IP, while the other uses the Hostname command to get the machine name.