# How to set reduce tasks based on cluster size in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I'd like to **set the # of reduce tasks** to be exactly equal to the # of available reduce slots in one job.

By default the reduce tasks are being calculated as ~1.75 times the # of reduce slots available (on Elastic Mapreduce). I notice that my job completes reduce tasks very uniformly, so it will better to run 1 reducer per reduce slot in the job.

But **how can I identify the cluster metrics** from within my job configuration?

Comment: Have you looked at this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11523480/how-to-collect-hadoop-cluster-size-number-of-cores-information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [ClusterMetrics](http://people.apache.org/~tomwhite/MAPREDUCE-1623/docs/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/ClusterMetrics.html) Class to get the status information on the current state of the Map-Reduce cluster, like Size of the cluster, Number of blacklisted and decommissioned trackers, Slot capacity of the cluster, The number of currently occupied/reserved map & reduce slots etc.