# Get Domain Name in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlet-3.0

When I am hosting my app on server, I need to know the domain name of my server. Here I was using `request.getRequestURL()` method and it is returning me http://127.0.0.1:9901/moobyle/home where I was expecting http://epdlbd.com:8080/moobyle/home

I also tried `request.getLocalName()` and `request.getServerName()` to get only **epdlbd.com** but its only returning `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`

> Is there any way that I can get my desired output(epdlbd.com)?

Comment: Those methods return the hostname or IP address that was used by the client to access the page.

Comment: Then what's my solution?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596788/get-dns-name-of-local-machine-as-seen-by-a-remote-machine

Comment: @user7294900, sorry, it could not help me.