# Fetching user name (windows) from a java application

Tags: java, windows, networking, windows-xp, user-management

**Problem:**

I am logging into a  virtual machine(RDC) using the below credentials:

The user is part of a domain group called as teldept

> user:147852 pass:helloworld

when i try to get the user details from java application it gives me : 147852

but when i click on start menu at the top i can see my Name displayed.

How is this done? i want to access this name from java application

I use the below snippet:

> System.getProperty("user.name");

**Whatever the above snippet gives me is correct as aper oracle docs.
I am logging in with ID: 147852 and above snippet gives me 14852
but some how in windows this ID:147852 is mapped with my name so only in the start menu in XP i am getting my name displyed instead of 147852. we need to know how this mapping is done between the ID & Name . I am guessing it has something to do with Domain or some network logic which i am not good with .**

Comment: How are you getting the "147852"? Post that snippet of code.

Comment: @user93353 i have edited the question. I hope i was not clear on my point.

Comment: If you are running the java program from a command line - what does USERNAME env variable contain - try `echo %USERNAME%`

Comment: @user93353 thanks for your help . when i run the above suggested i am getting 147852

Comment: Have you tried my answer below - using new  com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem().getName(); what does that give?

Comment: @user93353 i got the same 147852 :-(

Comment: XP Start menu shows FullName, not Logon ID - it cannot be got from Java without using JNI - updated my answer to say this.

Answer (score 4):

The name shown on XP's start menu is not the logon name. It's Full Name Corresponding to the Logon Name. Not sure if your login is a local login or a domain login. If it's a local login, go to Admin Tools -> Computer Management -> Users and Groups -> Here against your username (147852), you will find a full name. 
If your login is a domain login, you can similarly lookup your name in Active Directory - or search for it at other places.

This is very OS Specific and cannot be found by Java. 
You will need to do this using JNI and Windows API - Calling `GetUserNameEx` or `NetUserGetInfo` depending on type of user.

If you just want to get your logon name (147852), calling `com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem().getName` is a better way than using `System.getProperty("user.name")`

Comment: But how do we get it if the username has spaces?

Answer (score 2):

From [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473446/java-current-machine-name-and-logged-in-user), you can use:

```
System.getProperty("user.name");
```

to return the currently logged in user. This will return the username string. I believe this is what you're asking for, but your question is rather unclear.