# System.getProperty("user.name") returns HOSTNAME instead of currently logged username

Tags: java, windows

Here

```
System.getProperty("user.name");
```

returns host-name of windows server 2008 machine instead of currently logged in user name.

Below is my code

```
final String user = System.getProperty("user.name");
logger.info("User Name : " + user);
```

I want to know how System.getProperty works in java and on windows server 2008? 
and 
why is it returning wrong value in this case?

Comment: Do you mean a user logged into Windows? Or a user logged into your web application (from a browser somewhere out in the world)?

Comment: @Duncan No.its just standalone application.no server

Comment: I am getting my username when i run this as part of a standalone java program

Comment: @Thilo i mean user logged into windows

Comment: Maybe helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16219490/14955

Comment: @Juned i was also getting that before some days back but now its not working.Thats why i want to know how exactly System.getProperty works on windows. On windows server 2008, environment variable USERNAME has value SYSTEM

Comment: @EJP earlier i was getting proper user name  on windows server 2008 but from last few days its returning HOSTNAME of machine insted of user name

Answer (score 6):

Just checked this: `System.getProperty("user.name");` returns the value from environment variable `USERNAME`, so check what `set USERNAME` says in CMD window

Comment: It says USERNAME=admin

Comment: Strange... anything special how your application is started? Maybe try Process Explorer from www.systernals.com to check what the actual environment of your running process is.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean with " i am passing command to that jar from my local machine"? With exactly what command do you invoke it?

Comment: i am invoking JAR file placed on windows server by passing command with JSCH EXEC channel and code given in the question is present in that jar file.Here if i am launching that jar file by directly copy paste this command on the command promt of windows server then its properly giving user.name but when i am executing this by passing command through JSCH EXEC channel its giving me op as INPUSCPC which is nothing but host name of that server

Comment: @Rohan: sounds like JSCH EXEC (whatever that is) is running your code in the context of the server's domain account.  Or perhaps is just setting up the environment in an odd way.  At any rate, that's where you need to look for a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

to display list of all properties that are set in java, try the below code

```
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        Properties prop = System.getProperties();
        Set<String> a = prop.stringPropertyNames();
        Iterator<String> keys = a.iterator();
        while (keys.hasNext())
        {
            String key = keys.next();
            String value = System.getProperty(key);
            System.out.println(key + "=" + value);
        }
   }
```

Comment: When i tried this one i am getting strage output.as user.name=>>>>Scripts.jar and java.class.path=>>>>INPUSCPC08216$ here Script.jar is the name of the jar file on windows server which i am trying to run from my local machine and when i am using user.name it is giving me output as INPUSCPC08216$

Comment: Can you give more explanation on what you are trying the get from the property name `user.name` or `java.class.path`

Comment: i am trying user.name and i am getting INPUSCPC08216$ which is nothing but the values of java.class.path as mentioned above

Comment: Now check with this edited code. you should be getting `user.name` correclty