# How to get system name dynamically?

Tags: java, mysql

Please I have a Java Desktop app which connects to a MySQL database and I would like to run the application over a network.

This is what I've done so far.
My Java application generates a batch file that points to the original local of the .jar file so I simply place this batch file in other client systems and run them so they simply find the .jar file on the server system and open the application.

But I have an issue, I have a scenario where I don't know the server's system name so I can't specify it in the MySQL database connection string.

Please how can I dynamically get the system name and pass it into the database connection string so the client systems can also connect to the same server or database?

Comment: You have to know your target server somehow to address him if you don't want to implement some kind of broadcast/detection mechanism.

Comment: Could you launch the `.jar` file with command line arguments? `java -jar myjar.jar -server 10.0.10.100` You could then parse these arguments in your main method.

Comment: I don't seem to understand you. But what if I write the server name into a text file and try reading it from the client system.... Again I'm getting the system name dynamically so the path specified would have to be different too. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you may find it useful if you want to know  how could we get username of any host [System.getProperty("user.name") returns HOSTNAME instead of currently logged username](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18353856/system-getpropertyuser-name-returns-hostname-instead-of-currently-logged-use)

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
 import java.net.InetAddress;
```

Code

```
String myip=(InetAddress.getLocalHost()).toString();
```

Here you will get pc name and ip address with a '/' separated

```
 String data[]=myip.split("/");

        System.out.println(data[0]);  // Machine name
        System.out.println(data[1]);  //Ip address
```