# How to access generic user's My Downloads folder in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, download, automation, autoit

I am writing some Selenium WebDriver and AutoIt Java Tests using Chrome.
When I download a file in Chrome, it automatically downloads it to the Downloads folder on my computer.
I am sharing this code project with multiple other users on a repository, and so I do not want to have my Downloads folder hard coded in with my specific username in it.

What I mean by this is let's say the user name on my computer is "Eamon." The downloads folder on my machine would be "C:\Users\Eamon\Downloads," but lets say my friend Mark downloads the project from the shared repository, his downloads folder will be located at "C:\Users\Mark\Downloads," yet as he pulls from the repository to see my updated code, the download location will still be hard coded as ""C:\Users\Eamon\Downloads" which will result in a "Folder does not exist" error.

Is there a way in java to access the generic Downloads folder on a machine that would change based on who the user of the machine is? This would help my test a lot.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990038/how-to-get-windows-username-in-java

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a Windows machine :

```
new File("C:/Users/" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "/Downloads/");
```

Could use similar snippets for any other operating system.

Comment: What about non-english windows installations (and not only windows, gnu/linux folders can also be internationalized)? There directory wouldn't be called that way.

Comment: The question was more around how to inject the username though. To answer you, I'm actually pretty sure this path is still valid in a non-english configuration, at least it was the case for me when I had a Windows configured in french.

Comment: Apparently not the case at least for **Program Files**: http://www.samlogic.net/articles/program-files-folder-different-languages.htm. It seems to imply that you can rely on environment variables containing the localized name of these folders

Answer (score 2):

String myHomePath= System.getProperty("user.home");

File file = new File(myHomePath+"/Downloads/" + fileName);

Note:
give file name with proper extension e.g foo.txt