# How to get the folder name of the user under C:\Users\'s

Tags: java

Value obtained by using `System.getProperty (" user.name ")` does not match folder name under `C:\Users\`

I wonder if there is a way to get the folder name under `C:\Users\` of the account you are currently using.

I am using Java.

Comment: the folder name? there is only one folder there?

Comment: start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990038/how-to-get-windows-username-in-java

Comment: What output are you getting now?

Comment: The user name obtained by the method listed on the link does not match the folder name under C:\Users\down.

Comment: My computer has only one folder, but other computers may have multiple accounts.

Comment: @정승리 and what is the user name obtained by the method listed? "SYSTEM" ? check the link I posted, and you might find out why

Comment: The output on the code is SODA ; however, under the Users folder, the SeungRI folder is located.

Comment: what is the username of the currently logged in user?

Comment: I am currently logged in as SODA.

Comment: I think I can handle it. The link you sent me was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: so ... how come the folder you are looking for under C:\users isn't called SODA ?

Answer (score 0):

Sometime the OS not get ("user.name"),but there can be another way, just try

String username = System.getProperty("user.name");

String username = System.getenv("USERNAME");