# How to Get Current windows loged in user in Java

Tags: java

We created one java web application, once user hit my web site it has to take login id as his windows credential login id, but in my case after hosting my web site it is returning server admin user as windows login id every time. Is there any way to get current windows user id in java web application.

If i open my website it has to show my name, if some has open that site it has to show his name.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Windows user details are not sent in plain HTTP requests, which makes it impossible for you to get them from a user in a web application without additional data supplied or changes to the local machine accessing the web page.

The hostname from which the request is sent is available in the request but that's it

Comment: i am able to get this in c#, asp.net application.

Comment: You can do this in .net but not java to my knowledge. use this to look at your code how ever windows doesn't expose the current user to web application for security reasons https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19990038/how-to-get-windows-username-in-java

Comment: We created one internal portal , if some one hit that portal with in the network it has to check his windows login id and authorize to access the web portal. We achieved this in c#  ,

Comment: Your talking about authorization there, did you have to manually input the username or get it out of the web page?

Comment: For this right i created one web api in c# that returns the logedin user id, but while accessing in java for me it is returning my name and i am the owner of that hosted server. B

Comment: But if some is trying to access that right i am getting 401 error

Comment: a 410 error is a permanently moved with no forwarding address, that's not a error that would be caused by a get user string, I would advise looking else where

Comment: no i am not taking manually, based on the current windows user of desk or laptop taking that user and validating in background

Comment: ah okay, you said 410 error in your comment before you edited it. if you are looking to do this I would stick to .net, its not possible in java

Comment: can't we access .net api in java?

Comment: yes you can, so separate the two out and use .net to auth the user and java for the web application

Answer (score 0):

You just can’t, for security reasons.