# Running "who -m" command from Java yields empty result

Tags: java, linux, command-line-interface

I am trying to find the current logged in username from Java.

```
Process p;
try
{
    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("who -m");
    p.waitFor();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    String line = "";
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);
}
catch (Exception e)
{

}
```

The above code does not print any result. However if i remove -m option, it prints user name and other details. And also i tested with other options like -s, -u. It all works except -m. Does anyone has an idea why is it so?

Note:
I am aware of

```
System.getProperty("user.name");
```

But that's not a solution in my case. I am calling a shell script in which "who -m" is used. So, I cannot use java classes.

Comment: did you try it on the command line?

Comment: My `who` man page says `who -m` displays "only hostname and user associated with stdin".  If standard input has been changed, you might have problems.

Comment: @jgr208 - Yes. I did. It works on command line but not within Java environment.

Comment: @ajb - Yes. I understand that's the case. Do you have any suggestion to overcome this?

Comment: there may be no way around this depending on what is happening to the shell. if the shell is blown away you may be out of luck.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'd like to focus on the actual problem for a minute. What exactly is it that you are trying to do, and why do you feel that parsing the output of `who` is the way to go? Both the hostname and the current username can be determined programmatically (and more portably) from within your Java application.

Comment: You might want to have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/473446/507519

Comment: @KarthikAndhamil If you use `ProcessBuilder` and redirect standard input to `"/dev/tty"`, maybe it will work, but this is just a wild guess.  And I think that using something besides `who -m` to find the information is a good idea.

Comment: @thkala - As I mentioned in my question, I am aware of that particular solution. But the problem is, I am calling a shell script in which there is a function that calls "who -m" command. And this shell script is accessed by different tools that are developed using different languages. It works everywhere except Java tool. So, I need to find a solution within shell script that would work with every other tool including Java.

Comment: so can you edit the shell script or not?

Comment: @jgr208 - Yes. I can edit the script for minimal change and the solution should work for other tools as well.

Comment: Please expand on other tools. well would changing the command be minimal change?

Answer (score 2):

The reason for what you are seeing is that the Java process launcher does not guarantee the existence of an associated TTY. Consider this example on the actual command line:

```
$ who -m
user   pts/8        2014-09-02 02:24
$ who -m </dev/null
$
```

Since the standard input is not associated with a terminal for the second `who` call, `who` cannot determine the associated user. Interestingly enough, redirecting `stdin` to `/dev/tty` does not appear to work either:

```
$ who -m </dev/tty
$
```

Quite honestly, unless determining the user associated with `stdin` is *exactly* what you are after, you should probably update your script to use `hostname` and e.g. `id -un` or whatever other means your shell interpretter may offer to determine the current user.

---

For those interested in the details, I did a little bit more digging for [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26216630/507519).

Comment: id -un will return "root" if the application run using sudo. But i need the actual user logged in.

Comment: @KarthikAndhamil: `sudo` sets the `SUDO_USER` variable in the environment, IIRC. You could just check for it...

Answer (score 0):

From the man page for who:

```
"-m  only hostname and user associated with stdin"
```

I gather that this means the who command knows the current user based on a "who just hit the return key?" criteria.  Given that you are running the command from the JVM, I would entirely expect something weird to happen.

If you're using a bash script, try this as a work around.

```
process=`ps | grep ps | cut -d ' ' -f2`
user=`who -u | grep $process | cut -d ' ' -f1`
```

Unfortunately I've never tried to make java and bash work togeather, sorry I cant be more helpful!

Comment: Thanks. But, this gives me empty string even if I run shell script directly from terminal.

Comment: Are you sure you are returning $user i.e. `echo $user` should return your username.