# Running "who am i" in a single command with sudo doesnt return anything

Tags: linux, bash, redhat

I am trying to run "who am i" command in a single line in the following way and it returns nothing.

```
echo $password | sudo -u user -S who am i
```

Even logname command doesn't work in this way.

```
echo $password | sudo -u user -S logname
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: "Who am i" or "who -m" is same command and that's different than whoami.

Comment: Huh. I have learned something today, thanks!

Comment: This is expected behavior for `who` but not for `logname`. Can you confirm that the latter doesn't output anything in an interactive bash session?

Comment: Logname command returns "logname: no login name"

Comment: And can you please explain why that is expected behavior for who command?

Comment: I believe that this behavior has the same root cause as the one encountered [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26123706/507519)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `who` is invoked with two arguments, the `-m` flag is activated. From the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/who):

```
-m
    only hostname and user associated with stdin
```

In your case, the standard input is a pipe, rather than a terminal, and `who` (or `logname`) cannot determine the associated user. Consider this shell command snippet:

```
$ who am i
user   pts/11       2014-09-04 00:15
$ logname
user
$ echo | who am i
$ echo | logname
logname: no login name
$
```

From the [GNU Coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) `who.c` source:

```
if (my_line_only)
  {
    ttyname_b = ttyname (STDIN_FILENO);
    if (!ttyname_b)
      return;
    if (STRNCMP_LIT (ttyname_b, DEV_DIR_WITH_TRAILING_SLASH) == 0)
      ttyname_b += DEV_DIR_LEN; /* Discard /dev/ prefix.  */
  }
```

Since `ttyname()` returns `NULL` on errors, such as the file descriptor not corresponding to a terminal (`ENOTTY`), `who -m` will return immediately when `stdin` is a pipe.

As for [`logname`](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1posix/logname/), its proper behavior is to return the string that would have been returned by the `getlogin()` function. Unfortunately, the bug section of [the `getlogin()` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getlogin) is quite clear:

> Note that glibc does not follow the POSIX specification and uses stdin instead of /dev/tty. A bug. (Other recent systems, like SunOS 5.8 and HP-UX 11.11 and FreeBSD 4.8 all return the login name also when stdin is redirected.)

Bottom line: you should probably update your code to use `hostname` and e.g. `id -un` or whatever other means your shell interpretter may offer to determine the current user. `who -m` and its friends are not very predictable - quite honestly the output of `who`, much like `ls`, has the distinct feel of being intended for humans, rather than machines.