# Can user.name be spoofed

Tags: java, security, environment

To get the name of the current user in a Java program, you can [simply fetch the value of the `user.name` system property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/473470/545127):

```
 System.getProperty("user.name");
```

But how secure is that? Can a user executing the program easily set this property to an arbitrary value (using a command-line argument of the JVM, for example) for common runtime environments? Can a user easily spoof this user name?

---

I ask because I am writing a command-line program that can be run by anyone, but allows some privileged operations only if the user is a special administrative user.

---

Note that since Java 11 the `user.name` property is effectively read only once the program starts, so malicious *program code* can not spoof it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes this value can be 'spoofed' and cannot be relied upon if the user is free to start the application.

Simply starting the app with the JVM arg `-Duser.name=someothername` will cause `System.getProperty("user.name")` to return that value.

Comment: For what it's worth, here's a (bit) safer way to get the user name in Java (snippet/gist): https://gist.github.com/octavian-nita/9089594

Answer (score 0):

For anyone possible landing on this ever again:

Using the cmd-command `whoami` and reading the input using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31635379/6707985) should be a more secure way of using the username as "validation".

Except, this can be spoofed as well, which might be harder for a cmd-command than for a JVM argument...