# Java - How do i run a particular DOS command through JLabel

Tags: java, swing, shell, batch-file, jlabel

I've a JLabel with some text on it and i would like to run "echo %USERNAME%" command through the JLabel so that once i've run the code on NetBeans IDE 8.2 it should print the USERNAME on the JLabel text of the following Windows 7 end user

For example : I've JLabel with the text : "Hello Visitor" 
I want to change Visitor to the USERNAME with the help of echo %USERNAME% so that it should print the USERNAME of the Windows 7 end user on the JLabel

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for responding to a question *with* a question, but you want to get the username of an account and store it in a string, then use it as an attribute of some object?

If so, there is a method called `System.getProperty("user.name");`

This is what I've understood your question to be, apologies if that is incorrect. Also for running shell commands (platform specific), I would use the ProcessBuilder or `Runtime.exec("%USERNAME");` depending on which version of Java you are using. With the latter of the two, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31635379/how-to-get-command-prompt-output-in-java) will also be helpful

Comment: Thanks for the reply but is there any way to run System.getProperty("user.name"); 
on the JLabel after code compilation on NetBeans

Comment: Well compiling your code is not the same as running it. If you wanted to run your code, compilation is not enough, you must let the JVM execute your code.

Comment: @ Brenann Oct thanks bro , i just finally got it running with the help of jLabel in Java i.e. jLabel.setText("Welcome " + System.getProperty("user.name"));

Comment: Amazing! Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is the Computer's User Name then by all means using the `System.getProperty("user.name");` is the way to go. However, if there are  other items you want to throw across the Windows Command Prompt then you might want to utilize something like this with a runCMD() method:

```
List<String> list = runCMD("/C echo %USERNAME%");
if (!list.isEmpty()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

Console will display the current User Name.

The method might look something like this:

```
public List<String> runCMD(String commandString) {
    // Remove CMD from the supplied Command String
    // if it exists.
    if (commandString.toLowerCase().startsWith("cmd ")) {
        commandString = commandString.substring(4);
    }

    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        // Fire up the Command Prompt and process the
        // supplied Command String.
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd " + commandString);
        // Read the process input stream of the command prompt.
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
            String line = null;
            // Store what is in the stream into our ArrayList.
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                result.add(line);
            }
        }
        p.destroy(); // Kill the process
        return result;
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("runCMD() Method Error! - IO Error during processing "
                         + "of the supplied command string!\n" + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } 
}
```