# How can I get network user name in java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, server, client

I need get a network user name, but I don't know how!

I try 
`"System.getenv("USERNAME")"`,

`"System.getProperty("user.name")"` and

`"new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem().getName()"`,

but didn't work, they get local user name, on server they get `"server806"` and may network user name is `"pc8695"`.

How can I get client user name on client pc??

Comment: How would you do it without Java? That is, is there a command-line utility in Windows that will return the info you want? Or, with JNA, even invoking an API might be fairly easy.

Comment: What exactly is a network user name? Are you talking about a specific network service? Your attempts should only give you the windows user...

Comment: I need get username logged on client machine

Comment: @user3061516 logged on where? in windows? That can be done using ``user.name``. Or in some other software?

Comment: on windows.
System.getenv("USERNAME") don't work on server, this get username from server.

Comment: I need get username logged on pc client

Answer (score 0):

Display all environment variables (name : value ) this way

```
 Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
    for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
        System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                          envName,
                          env.get(envName));
    }
```

Then see what key exactly you need.

Comment: don't get network username logged on pc client

Comment: Did you try this? `System.getProperty("user.name");` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/473446/java-current-machine-name-and-logged-in-user