# How to get current user name of Linux in Java

Tags: java, linux, jenkins

I have a Selenium tests written in Java which runs as Jenkins job. I need to have chmod set up to 777 cause otherwise it throws me an error. But I would like to set up chmod properly to somenthing like 775. The problem is that I dont know who is the user which runs the Java tests. I have this code in Java

```
System.out.println(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("whoami"));
```

which returns this: **Process[pid=2116487, exitValue=0]** Can somebody tell me please what is it? Obviously it is not a user I can set up as owner or as a group of the repository.

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get login username in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797549/get-login-username-in-java)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473446/java-current-machine-name-and-logged-in-user  check this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the output of the process, you need to attach the `InputStream` of to the normal output of the subprocess. Then, you can read from it by creating a `BufferedReader`. To get the first line of the output of the process (on stdout) you can use this code:

```java
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("whoami");
BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
String username = stdin.readLine();
System.out.println(username);
```

*You can also get the `InputStream` of the error output of the subprocess (stderr) with `proc.getErrorStream()` if this should be necessary.*

---

However, there is a better way if you want to get the username of the user executing the VM:

```
String username = System.getProperty("user.name");
System.out.println(username);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the output of the process "whoami", but the process properties. Try

```
System.out.println(new Printstream(Runtime.getRuntime().exec("whoami").getOutputStream()));
```

Comment: What namespace is Printstream?

Comment: java.io.PrintStream

Comment: BTW, my IDE (Eclipse) already proposed this namespace. And it showed the Javadoc for the command `exec`, which shows that the return of the function is the process properties. Your problem could have been avoided by using an IDE.

Comment: It was something between the PC and the chair. I have InteliJ IDEA for it. I saw more than one packege for Pritstream. Now it is only one. Unbelievable...

Comment: Sometimes a little break or sleep resolves all problems... ;)

Comment: Ok but this command does not write to the console output.

Comment: Thanks, I had a typo in the code (the best place for typos...)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this?

```
System.getProperty("user.name")
```